# Meteor: How Should I Build Form

Tags: jquery, forms, meteor

I need to build a form that a user can select one out of a few choices, then the next set of choices show up, then the user select one out of those choises, and so on.

Should I build this using JavaScript of jQuery, or using a meteor form package?

I'm an intermediate JS/jQuery user and a meteor beginner.

Comment: http://www.neo.com/2014/05/23/reactive-forms-in-meteor-js Have you read this? It might be what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will require some learning but I recommend: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/

It's great package and it has a lot of support and lots of add-ons you should check it out.

demo: http://autoform.meteor.com/